# Как задать несколько ключей для одного значения в словаре(dict)

Tags: python-3.x, dict

Ниже мой код для решения этой [задачи](http://acmp.ru/index.asp?main=task&id_task=892)

```
    l = 'Summer'
    v = 'Spring'
    o = 'Autumn'
    z = 'Winter'
    b = {1 : z, 2 : z, 3 : v, 4 : v,
         5 : v, 6 : l, 7 : l, 8 : l, 9 : o, 10 : o, 11 : o, 12 : z}
    a = int(input())
    if a < 1 or a > 12:
      print('Error')
    else:
        print(b[a])
```

Как мне задать несколько ключей, чтобы было что то типа 1, 2 , 12 = 'Winter' ? И если не трудно предложите самые короткие способы своего решения, буду благодарен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так полагаю, вы имеете в виду, что-то вроде этого:

```
monthsBySeason = {
  'winter': [12, 1, 2],
  'spring': [3, 4, 5],
  'summer': [6, 7, 8],
  'autumn': [9, 10, 11]
}

userInput = int(input())
userOutput = ''

for season in monthsBySeason:
  if userInput in monthsBySeason[season]:
      userOutput = season.capitalize()
      break
  else:
      userOutput = 'There is no such month'

print(userOutput)
```

Также, хочу обратить ваше внимание, что некоторые, - особенно европейцы, - любят считать наступление нового сезона по-другому. В связи с этим вот вам еще один [пример](https://www.w3resource.com/python-exercises/python-conditional-exercise-37.php).

Вы так же можете принять следующий массив за "карту" сезонов:

```
[1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 1]
```

Здесь особую роль будут играть индексы - нулевой и первый это Зима, 2ой/3ий/4ый это Весна. И т.д. Тогда можно получить что-то вроде этого:

```
month = int(input())
seasons = ['Winter', 'Spring', 'Summer', 'Autumn']
monthsBySeason = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 1]

if month < 1 or month > 12:
  print('There is not such month')
else:
  print(seasons[monthsBySeason[month - 1] - 1])
```